# Unintended changes in dictionary's content when solving the coin change problem

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, dynamic-programming

The problem I was trying to solve was: given a list of coins and a sum, find out all the possible ways to form the sum using those coins (you can use one coin infinite amount of time)
For example: 4 and [1,2,3] will give the answer [1,1,1,1], [1,1,2], [2,2], [1,3] (here, there are three types of coins, those with value of 1, 2 and 3).
Here is my attempt of the problem:

```
def coin_check(target_sum, numbers):
    memo = {}

    def helper(target_sum, numbers):
        if target_sum == 0:
            return [[0]]
        if target_sum in memo:
            return memo[target_sum]
        memo[target_sum] = []
        for num in numbers:
            remainder = target_sum - num
            if remainder >= 0:
                combination = helper(remainder, numbers)
                if combination != []:
                    for i in combination:
                        i.append(num)
                        memo[target_sum].append(i)
        print(memo)
        return memo[target_sum]
    return helper(target_sum, numbers)
print(coin_check(4,[1,2,3]))
```

Here I try to use dynamic programming to keep track of which value I have already tried. The answer I got was:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 3]]
```

which is of course incorrect. The evolution of the memo after the the program has run was:

```
{4: [], 3: [], 2: [], 1: [[0, 1]]}
{4: [], 3: [], 2: [[0, 1, 1], [0, 2]], 1: [[0, 1, 1]]}
{4: [], 3: [[0, 1, 1, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 2], [0, 3]], 2: [[0, 1, 1, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1]], 1: [[0, 1, 1, 1, 2]]}
{4: [[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]], 3: [[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 1]], 2: [[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 1, 2]], 1: [[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]]}
```

This puzzles me because I can't see where in my program did I say to change the value of memo[1] into [0,1,1] afterward [0,1] has already existed. Can someone please explain to me why this is happening, thank you.

P.s: here, my algorithm always puts 0 in each possible combination.

Comment: Interesting. I can't see at a glance where the issue comes from. Once you've solved the issue and your program works as expected, I recommend reading about [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and using it to simplify the code of this function a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is this line:

```
i.append(num)
```

This *mutates* a list that was potentially already put in `memo` in the deeper recursive call. You should create a new list instead:

```
memo[target_sum].append(i + [num])
```

There are also the following issues:

- The following code...

  ```
  return [[0]]
  ```

  ... will make that *every* combination will include the value 0, since they are all built by extending this base case. You should instead do:

  ```
  return [[]]
  ```
- With this code...

  ```
  for num in numbers:
      remainder = target_sum - num
  ```

  ... you are reducing `remainder` in a *accumulative* way, i.e. you don't *undo* the change to `remainder` at the end of an iteration of the loop. Instead, don't use this variable at all, and keep the reduced expression dynamic:

  ```
  for num in numbers:
      if target_sum >= num:
          combination = helper(target_sum - num, numbers)
  ```

With these corrections you'll already get a more reasonable result.

There is just one more thing missing: all permutations of a solution are *also* included. As you want those excluded, you'll need to tell the recursive call from which coin onwards coins may be selected. This requires a bit more changes, but it could look like this:

```
def coin_check(target_sum, numbers):
    memo = {}

    def helper(target_sum, mincoin):
        if target_sum == 0:
            return [[]]
        if target_sum in memo:
            # get memo, but only return combis that obey mincoin restriction
            return [row for row in memo[target_sum] if row[0] >= mincoin]
        memo[target_sum] = []
        for coinid in range(mincoin, len(numbers)):
            num = numbers[coinid]
            if target_sum >= num:
                combination = helper(target_sum - num, coinid)
                if combination != []:
                    for combi in combination:
                        # prefix with coinid
                        memo[target_sum].append([coinid] + combi)
        return memo[target_sum]
    
    # Convert coin id to coin value
    return [
        [numbers[coinid] for coinid in combi] 
            for combi in helper(target_sum, 0)
    ]


print(coin_check(4, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 16 of your snippet, when you append `num` to each possible remainder combination, you are actually directly changing the lists stored in `memo`.

This happens because in python, when you grab a list and store it in a variable, that variable actually holds a pointer to that list's address in memory, rather than a copy of the list.

This can be demonstrated by executing:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a
b.append(3)
print(a)
```

You will notice that the output is `[1, 2, 3]`, because `b` actually contains a *pointer* to the list, rather than a copy of it. **There is still only one list in memory**.

A useful check is to evaluate the lists by using `is`. If `a`and `b` point to the same list in memory, then

`a is b`

will evaluate to `True`. It is important to understand that `is` and `==` are **not** the same operator.

Going back to the problem, this means that whenever `i` is altered, the entry in `memo` is altered too, because `combination` is actually a list of pointers to lists in `memo`. This is clearly something you want to avoid.

Instead, before appending `num` to `i`, copy `i` into a new, detached list using `i.copy()` to prevent the actual data in `memo` from being changed.

Instead of:

```
for i in combination:
    i.append(num)
    memo[target_sum].append(i)
```

Try:

```
for i in combination:
    j = i.copy()
    j.append(num)
    memo[target_sum].append(j)
```